# How to apply function to QoQ Data

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(DATE=c(201403,201406,201409,201412,201503,201506,201509), BALANCE = c(126,132,137,139,136,135,134), INCOME=c(288,298,303,303,299,297,292))
```

return,

```
     DATE BALANCE INCOME
1: 201403     126    288
2: 201406     132    298
3: 201409     137    303
4: 201412     139    303
5: 201503     136    299
6: 201506     135    297
7: 201509     134    292
```

I would like to calculate, for example, in 2015 Q3, the value will be (136-126)/(288 - 126) = 0.06.  The completed result will be as follows:

```
     DATE BALANCE INCOME CHANGE
1: 201403     126    288     NA
2: 201406     132    298     NA
3: 201409     137    303     NA
4: 201412     139    303     NA
5: 201503     136    299  0.060
6: 201506     135    297  0.017
7: 201509     134    292 -0.016
```

Could you please suggest?

Comment: Anything you've already tried yourself? Why did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to run these calculations over a sub-string of `DATE` (while making sure it is ordered)

```
mydt[order(DATE), 
     CHANGE := c(NA, round(diff(BALANCE)/(INCOME[1L] - BALANCE[1L]), 3L)), 
     by = substr(DATE, 5L, 6L)]
mydt
#      DATE BALANCE INCOME CHANGE
# 1: 201403     126    288     NA
# 2: 201406     132    298     NA
# 3: 201409     137    303     NA
# 4: 201412     139    303     NA
# 5: 201503     136    299  0.062
# 6: 201506     135    297  0.018
# 7: 201509     134    292 -0.018
```

Your calculations seem a bit off. Also, this will work only on a two years data, it will need to be generalized of you have many years and you want a rolling comparison, but this will get you started.

Comment: I think some `shift`s should be enough to generalize it: `mydt[ , CHANGE := (BALANCE-shift(BALANCE,type="lag"))/shift(INCOME-BALANCE,type="lag"), by=.(substr(DATE,5,6))]` Not sure if the OP would figure that out without knowing of that function.

Comment: Nice one @Frank, shift will probably do the job for several years.